# Inheritance, protected or setters, getters

Tags: java, inheritance

I have the basis class.Animal(abstract)
and some classes (dog,cat...) extend this class.
I have some values that must be in every object of animal.
some function in dog,cat... use this values and sometimes change them.
I want if I need to create in Animal getter & setter to this values or put this values protected. what is the good way to do this.
also some of this values must be initialize.there is a way to do this values absract?

Comment: The short answer is yes, if you want some member in a superclass to be present in a subclass, you should make that member `protected`.

Comment: I know that I can make it protected. but does it better to make setter and getters ,in this way I can make the setter as abstract?

Comment: I would always use getters and setters from anywhere outside the class, because if the logic changes when setting a field it can be done in the setter. Imagine for example you have a method 'walk' that takes a String. But later you decide that you want to use it as an integer. Instead of going through all of your subclasses and changing it to an integer, you just add some 'parseInt' logic to the setter and voila

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make the properties protected in Animal, so that they can be referenced directly in subclasses (Dog and Cat), but have public getters and setters for access anywhere else.

```
public abstract class Animal {
    protected String species;
    ...
    public String getSpecies(){
        return species;
    }
    public void setSpecies(String species){
        this.species = species;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the values in the Animal class, and create public getters and setters. These will then be available on all dogs, cats, fish etc

Answer (score 0):

Use getters and setters, it's the standard Java approach, eliminates confusion as to where the variable is coming from and allows parent classes to do whatever pre/post processing they need to do on the values (such as validation on setting or lazy initializing on getting).  Also, in a lot of aspect oriented programming (important if you use or plan on using Spring) relies on method call interception, using getters and setters will help with that as well.